# Create multiple lists from filtering a list of several dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I Have multiple dictionaries in a list. These dictionaries each contain a company name and the parts they build. I would like to create a function that return a NEW list of companies that make a certain part (some do, some don't).

I've managed to create a list extracting all the names (values) from the list containing the dictionaries. I "Think" i've managed to create a function that, given a part argument, can go through each dict and append in a new list all the company names that make that part. But i need this function to be so that depending on which part i pass as an argument it would create a different list everytime and not (as the code does) just overwrite the list.

```
maker1 = {'Name': 'A', 'Parts': ('Eggs', 'Bacon', 'Spam')}
maker2 = {'Name': 'B', 'Parts': ('Eggs', 'Spam')}
maker3 = {'Name': 'C', 'Parts': ('Bacon', 'Beans')}
maker4 = {'Name': 'D', 'Parts': ('Bacon', 'Spam', 'ExtraSpam')}
makerlist = [maker1, maker2, maker3, maker4]


def maker_names(list1):
    maker_names = []
    for maker in range(len(list1)):
        maker_names.append(list1[maker]['Name'])
    print(maker_names)

def part_makers(part_name):
    part_makers = []
    for key in range(len(makerlist)):
        if part_name in makerlist[key]['Parts']:
            part_makers.append(makerlist[key]['Name'])
    print(part_makers)

maker_names(makerlist)
part_makers('Eggs')
part_makers('Beans')
```

This works as it should (i think), but i cant figure out the next step. I've looked into maybe going for dict comprehensions but i am stuck there as well.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `collectios.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def part_makers(maker_list):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for i in maker_list:
        for p in i['Parts']:
            d[p].append(i['Name'])
    return d
part_makers(makerlist)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'Eggs': ['A', 'B'],
             'Bacon': ['A', 'C', 'D'],
             'Spam': ['A', 'B', 'D'],
             'Beans': ['C'],
             'ExtraSpam': ['D']})
```

From which you can use:

```
partmakers = part_makers(makerlist)
partmakers['Eggs']
# ['A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the desired outcome by using a list comprehension with the `makerlist`    you've created of all the dictionaries

```
makerlist = [maker1, maker2, maker3, maker4]
def part_makers(makerlist,part):
    return [m['Name'] for m in makerlist if part in m['Parts']]
```

example:

```
part_makers(makerlist,'Spam')
```

output:

```
['A', 'B', 'D']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the filter method is the simplest way to do it:

```
makerlist = [maker1, maker2, maker3, maker4]


def part_makers(part):
    new_list = list(filter(lambda company: part in company.get('Parts'), makerlist))
    return [company.get('Name') for company in new_list]


print(part_makers("Eggs"))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B']
```